# auth0 DRF authenticates correctly on localhost but does not on heroku hosted angular app talking to a heroku hosted DRF app

Tags: angular, authentication, heroku, django-rest-framework, auth0

I have done a video call sharing my screen with auth0 and they were not able to help me.

I have a angular app talking to a DRF app.

There is no difference in the code between what is hosted on my localhost and what is hosted in both of the heroku instances.

Yet authentication is only properly occurring while my localhost front end is talking to my localhost backend.

localhost to heroku backend fails

heroku front end to localhost backend via tunnel fails

When the code fails what I mean is endpoints of the servers work fine. But authentication continues to return AnoymousUser

here is a screen of the heroku hosted DRF logs when I go to a protected endpoint.[click here for picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V9jx9.png)

I have been on a video call sharing my screen with auth0 and it was of no help.

I am confident, this isn't a code issue, but is a network issue and I am making zero progress on solving this.

I am interested in keeping this question to what the difference between local host and heroku hosted that may be breaking auth

Thank you all for taking time to read this.

Answer (score 0):

never mind i didn't add the new value to my httpInterceptor code